# Python docstring escaping tabs and universal newlines

Tags: python, string, docstring

I'd appreciate some help on an efficient Pythonic solution for this problem.

Our internal coding standards mandate certain information fields should be in a block comment at the top of the file. In Perl, this was obviously a block of text beginning with '#'.

I'm experimenting with including this information in the module docstring in Python. The problem is I need to access some of this information in the program.

I have surgically extended docstring_parser to recognise the information fields, and create a data structure. This all works.

Except that one of the fields includes the source file location. That's fine on Unix, but we are a cross platform shop, and Windows uses '\' as a path separator. Python decides to process this as universal newlines and tabs, with weird results.

So the string `%workspace%\PythonLib\rr2\tests\test_rr2.py`

get rendered as:

```
%workspace%\PythonLib
r2      ests    est_rr2.py
```

which isn't exactly readable anymore.

The fix I have attempted is based on repeated applications of str.replace(), but is there a better way?

Comment: Use a raw string.

Comment: Thank you - it didn't occur to me that you could make a docstring raw!

Answer (score 1):

@user2357112 is correct. The docstring can be made raw by beginning it with `r"""`, and then everything works.